# C#_ Casting variable types foreach loop

Tags: c#

I have ran in to a problem with a foreach loop. I have a class named `SmartAgent` and a class named `Population`. The population class has a List of type SmartAgent which contains all my Agents and functions Live,Display,Reproduction,Selection and Fitness.

The code cant compile because in the foreach loop the variable type is Population and its trying to iterate through its population list of type Smart Agent. The error I am getting is:

> Error (CS0030): Cannot convert type 'Script_Instance.SmartAgent' to 'Script_Instance.Population' (line 113)

******Question: is there a way to "cast" Population to be type SmartAgent? or what is the most correct way in programming to deal with such issues?**

Thank you!

Nicholas

here is the part of the program:

```
Population population = new Population(number, 0.01);


if(run){

  if(geneCounter < lifespan)
  {
     foreach(Population P in population.population){



      P.Live();
      P.display();



    }


 else
  {

      foreach( Population P in population.population){

      P.Fitness();
      P.Selection();
      P.Reproduction();

     }


  }
```

///-------------------------SMART AGENT--------------------------//////////

```
public class SmartAgent
{
public Point3d location; 
public Vector3d velocity; 
public Vector3d acceleration; 
DNA dna = new DNA();
public double fitness = 0; // each agent will now its own fitness value

public SmartAgent(Point3d Location, Vector3d Velocity, Vector3d Acceleration)
{
  location = Location;
  velocity = Velocity;
  acceleration = Acceleration;
}

public SmartAgent(Point3d Location, DNA Dna)
{
  acceleration = new Vector3d();
  velocity = new Vector3d();
  location = Location;
  dna = Dna;

}

public void ApplyForce(Vector3d force)
{

  force.Unitize();
  force *= maxForce; // constrain force by a scalar value
  acceleration += force; // Update acceleration
}

public void Fitness()
{
  double distanceToTarget = location.DistanceTo(t.location);
  fitness = 1 / distanceToTarget;

  if(distanceToTarget <= 50)
  {
    fitness *= 2;

  }

}

public void Update()
{
  double maxSpeed = 0.6;

  updateGenes();
  Bounds();
  velocity += acceleration;
  location += velocity * maxSpeed;
  acceleration *= 0;
}


public void updateGenes()
{
  //geneCounter++; // Update gene counter by 1
  //dna.Genes();   // Create a random velocity vector through each iteration
  ApplyForce(dna.geneList[geneCounter]); // Apply a force from geneList

}

public Point3d display()
{

  Point3d agentDisplay = new Point3d(location.X, location.Y, location.Z);

  return agentDisplay;
}
}
```

Population

```
public class Population
{
//-----PROPERTIES-------//

public int size;
public List<SmartAgent> population;// = new List<SmartAgent>();
public List <SmartAgent> matingPool;// = new List <Vector3d>();
int generations;
double mutationRate;

//-----CONSTRUCTOR-------//
public Population(int Size, double MutationRate)
{
  size = Size;
  mutationRate = MutationRate;
  generations = 0;
  population = new List<SmartAgent>();
  matingPool = new List<SmartAgent>();

  // create a population of Smart Agents
  // with initial random velocities that are inside the
  //DNA() constructor

  for(int i = 0;i < size;i++)
  {
    Point3d location = new Point3d(0, 0, 0);

    population.Add(new SmartAgent(location, new DNA()));
  }

}
//-----METHODS-------//

public void Live()
{
  foreach (SmartAgent agent in population)
  {
    agent.Update();
  }
}

public Point3d display()
{
  Point3d test = new Point3d();

  foreach (SmartAgent agent in population)
  {
    test = agent.display();
  }

  return test;

}

public Vector3d VelocityDisplay()
{
  Vector3d test = new Vector3d();

  foreach (SmartAgent agent in population)
  {

    test = agent.velocity;
  }

  return test;
}


public void Fitness()
{
  foreach (SmartAgent agent in population)
  {
    agent.Fitness();
  }
}

//--------------SELECTION-------------///

public void Selection()
{
  matingPool.Clear();
  double maxFitness = getMaxFitness();

  foreach (SmartAgent agent in population)
  {
    double fitnessNormal = Map(0, maxFitness, 0, 1, agent.getFitness());

    int n = (int) (fitnessNormal * 100);

    for( int j = 0;j < n;j++)
    {
      matingPool.Add(agent);  
    }
  }
}

public void Reproduction()
{


  foreach (SmartAgent agent in population)
  {

    int indexA = ran.Next(0, matingPool.Count);
    int indexB = ran.Next(0, matingPool.Count);

    if(indexA == indexB)
    {
      indexA += 1;
    }

    // pick parents

    SmartAgent parentA = matingPool[indexA];

    SmartAgent parentB = matingPool[indexB];

    // get parent genes

    DNA parentAGenes = parentA.getDNA();
    DNA parentBGenes = parentB.getDNA();

    // produce child

    DNA child = parentBGenes.CrossOver(parentAGenes);

    // gene mutation

    child.Mutation(mutationRate);

    // create new population with next generation

    Point3d location = new Point3d();
    population.Add(new SmartAgent(location, child));

  }

  generations++;
}


public double getMaxFitness()
{
  double record = 0;

  //for(int i = 0;i < population.Count;i++)
  foreach (SmartAgent agent in population)
  {
    if(agent.getFitness() > record)
    {
      record = agent.getFitness();

    }
  }

  return record;
}

}
```

Comment: What is `population.population`? Assuming that's your list of SmartAgents, your foreach loops should be `foreach (SmartAgent s in population.population)`

Comment: Hi nlwalker, thank you for your reply, population.population contains my list of SmartAgents, how ever I the foor loop cant be of type SmartAgent becuase that class dosent contain the display, live, fitness, selection and reproduction methods.

Comment: If that's the case, you need to change your calls to `P.Live()`, `P.display()` etc. to `population.Live()`, `population.display()` and so on, because that's the object you're calling them on.

Comment: Show us the `Population` and `SmartAgent` classes.

Comment: Just added both classes to the post (:

Comment: It looks like all the methods you are calling in `Population` do their own looping through the `population` list in the object instance. Are you sure you actually need foreach loops in the place you're asking about?

Comment: You cannot cast `SmartAgent` to `Population`. Review the conversion rules https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#explicit-reference-conversions. It is unclear what you are trying to do. Your foreach loop needs to change as `population.population` is a `List<SmartAgent>` therefore each item will be a `SmartAgent` which can only access SmartAgent methods.

Answer (score 0):

If `population.popuation` is actually a collection of `SmartAgent` instances, then try using that as the expected type in your `foreach`

```
foreach(SmartAgent a in population.population){
    a.Live();
    a.display();
}
```

Comment: Hey Scott thanks for your reply. If I make the loop of type SmartAgent, I will still not compile because my class SmartAgent dosnt contain the methods of live, display.. etc

Answer (score 0):

Is smartagent supposed to be child class of population?

Why are you trying to run a 'live' function on a smartagent if the display and live functions are from population, what are these functions meant to achieve?

I suspect what the solution will be is a restructuring of how your classes work rather than the foreach loop.

Say for example display and live are run by population, they could take an integer for the indedx of the agent or simply the object of type smartagent to update the display or live functions in reference to a particular agent. ie:

```
foreach(SmartAgent item in population.population) {
    population.live(item);
    population.display(item); }
```

Or you could put the functions live() and display() on the individual class smartagent, ie:

```
foreach(SmartAgent item in population.population) {
    item.live();
    item.display(); }
```

Another option would be to have the live and display functions do the loops themseleves.